# Google Drive API insufficientFilePermissions error

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Hi I am receiving an error of insufficientFilePermissions when transfering ownership of a file.

What I did is, create a permission of writer for the Main email address (need to be the owner). Then it returned permission object.

I used the permission.id in the URL as a parameter. Then role property on request body.

I am currently logged in as the current owner of the file using OAuth 2. what is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your apps have [sufficient scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need) the it needs.

Also, try to delete your previously save credentials related file or browser cache if any.

Your [error](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) indicates that you don't have write access to a file, and the app is attempting to modify that file.

> Suggested action: Report to the user that there is a need to ask for
>   those permissions in order to update the file. You may also want to
>   check user access levels in the metadata retrieved by [`files.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
>   and use that to change your UI to a read only UI.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure owner of the file is someone of same domain because transfer ownership us not supported across domain.